# Can I put AttributeConverter into data entity?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am using AttributeConverter for converting enum short code in DB. Everything work fine. And the sample is here:

Data class(User):

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
  private Long id;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  @Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
  @Convert(converter = StatusConverter.class)
  private Status status;

  @Getter
  public enum Status {
    Active("A"),
    Inactive("I"),
    ;

    private String shortCode;

    Status(String s){
      this.shortCode= s;
    }

    public static Status of(String s) {
       for (Status _enum: Status.values()) {
         if (_enum.getType().equals(s.trim())) {
           return _enum;
         }
       }
       return null;
    }
  }
}
```

User's StatusConverter class(User):

```
@Converter
public class StatusConverter implements AttributeConverter<User.Status, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(User.Status status) {
        return status.getType();
    }

    @Override
    public User.Status convertToEntityAttribute(String s) {
        return User.Status.of(s);
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine.

But if I have another data class with its own status like this:

```
// Example Only
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "case")
public class Case {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
  private Long id;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  @Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
  @Convert(converter = StatusConverter.class) // There should be fail to convert
  private Case.Status status;

  @Getter
  public enum Status {
    Waiting("W"),
    Processing("P"),
    Closed("C"),
    Cancelled("X"),
    ;

    private String shortCode;

    Status(String s){
      this.shortCode= s;
    }

    public static Status of(String s) {
       for (Status _enum: Status.values()) {
         if (_enum.getType().equals(s.trim())) {
           return _enum;
         }
       }
       return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Although the easiest solution is that create an AttributeConverter named "CaseStatusConverter" for Case Status, the User StatusConverter is used for User Status. So I think it should be moved into the User data class as an inner class like this:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
  private Long id;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  @Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
  @Convert(converter = StatusConverter.class)
  private Status status;

  @Getter
  public enum Status {
    Active("A"),
    Inactive("I"),
    ;

    private String shortCode;

    Status(String s){
      this.shortCode= s;
    }

    public static Status of(String s) {
       for (Status _enum: Status.values()) {
         if (_enum.getType().equals(s.trim())) {
           return _enum;
         }
       }
       return null;
    }
  }

  @Converter
  public class StatusConverter implements AttributeConverter<User.Status, String> {

      @Override
      public String convertToDatabaseColumn(User.Status status) {
          return status.getType();
      }

      @Override
      public User.Status convertToEntityAttribute(String s) {
          return User.Status.of(s);
      }
  }
  
}
```

After moving, the User StatusConverter is no longer working. Can I move the StatusConverter into the data class as a inner class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can move the StatusConverter into the data class User as an inner class. However, when using inner classes as converters, you need to ensure that the inner class is declared as static. This is because JPA requires attribute converters to be stateless, and declaring the inner class as static ensures that it doesn't have a reference to the outer class instance.

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
  private Long id;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  @Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
  private Status status;

  @Getter
  public enum Status {
    Active("A"),
    Inactive("I"),
    ;

    private String shortCode;

    Status(String s){
      this.shortCode= s;
    }

    public static Status of(String s) {
       for (Status _enum: Status.values()) {
         if (_enum.getType().equals(s.trim())) {
           return _enum;
         }
       }
       return null;
    }
  }

  @Converter(autoApply = true)
  public class StatusConverter implements AttributeConverter<User.Status, String> {

      @Override
      public String convertToDatabaseColumn(User.Status status) {
          return status.getType();
      }

      @Override
      public User.Status convertToEntityAttribute(String s) {
          return User.Status.of(s);
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: "JPA requires attribute converters to be stateless" <- According to this reason, should I declare all the attribute converters class as static even not an inner class?

Comment: I modified the code with auto=true for annotation. And Yes, according to the requirement that attribute converters in JPA should be stateless, it is recommended to declare them as static classes, even if they are not inner classes.